# Get Filtered Data From HubDB from Multiple Select Column

Tags: hubspot

I have a Table in HubDB as follows...

[image]

I have Filter data by Gender by Following Code Snippet

```
{% for row in hubdb_table_rows(675094, 'gender=1') %}
```

But, Now i want to **filter Data by Multiple Filed**. I'm stuck here. 
I want data which has **M5** value in Multiple Filed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple limits to your query with an `&`.
I haven't tested it but it should be something like:

```
{% for row in hubdb_table_rows(675094, 'gender=1&multiple_feed=M5') %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple limits to your query with an &.
I haven't tested it but it should be something like:

{% for row in hubdb_table_rows(675094, 'gender=1&multiple_feed__contains=M5') %}